# Как с помощью canvas создать фигуры?

Tags: javascript, canvas

подскажите как вот нарисовать такую фигуру с помощью Canvas?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой компонент Mask, добавив его на родителя (UI) все дочерние объекты не будут выходить за его рамки, т.е. если взять ваше изображения и сделать черным, после чего закинуть в Image (родитель) и потом добавить Image (дочерний) с любой картинкой, и при этом Mask на родителе то получиться ваш результат